# If there a way to get growl notifications on grunt protractor failures?

Tags: macos, gruntjs, protractor, growl

I'm on OSX, and have a grunt watch file with jshint & protractor tests. I get growl notifications from the jshint messages, but none from protractor failures. I would prefer to get a visible popup notification rather than having to inspect the terminal output.

Any suggestions?

The packages used are:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-jshint' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-watch' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-http-server' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-protractor-webdriver' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-protractor-runner' );
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-notify' );

grunt.task.run( 'http-server:test' );
grunt.task.run( 'protractor_webdriver:test' );
grunt.task.run( 'notify_hooks' );
```

Comment: Have you tried configuring `grunt-notify` to work with it? Maybe using a custom task config? Or `grunt-protractor`?

Comment: I had grunt-notify & grunt-protractor-runner installed. It seems the key is to set the protractor keepAlive option to false so that it exits on failure, which causes a growl notification.

Comment: So that worked then? Great. BTW: in the future you'll want to post your whole gruntfile or at least the areas that relate to the tasks in question, since based on your code we can't know what you've tried and not tried :)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with some minor setup.   You need to enable growl in your [protractor setup](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/frameworks.md).

```
mochaOpts: {
  reporter: "spec",
  slow: 3000,
  growl: true
}
```

And make sure [growl is enabled in your setup](https://github.com/tj/node-growl#installation)

Comment: Thanks, but i'm using the default jasmine framework that comes with protractor, not mocha.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for this

```
npm install --save-dev protractor-notify-plugin
```

You can add to your protractor.conf.js file in the plugins section

```
plugins: [{
    package: 'protractor-notify-plugin',
    notifier: 'growl'
}]
```

Maybe check it out here https://github.com/el-davo/protractor-notify-plugin